# Survey tool without admin being able to manipulate responses

Tags: web-apps, privacy, survey

I am looking for a website where I can create an anonymous feedback form where people from my study project can give me anonymous feedback in free text form. It is very important for me that the creator (which would be me) can't theoretically manipulate the responses (e.g. in Google Forms, the creator sadly can delete individual responses, so I could theoretically delete responses I don't like). I have been googling and looking at lists of survey software for about half an hour now but could only find tools where the creator can delete responses (which I find quite sad).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: That's pretty much the definition of "admin". He can do anything, including delete/tamper with the data. At some point some trust must be placed.

Comment: I suppose I picked a bad word. Changing it from "admin" to "creator"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a sense, I have found out that after all, Google Forms seems to fulfill my requirements. One can do the following to resolve the issue I describe in my question:

1. From Google Forms, create a Google Sheets that automatically records the responses
2. If someone claims that the creator removed a response, the claim could be verified as follows:

   1. Share e.g. via screenshare your screen and go over the revision history of the spreadsheet around when the alleged removal happened to see if it really happened or not. The good thing is that the revision history of a Google Sheets can't be manipulated, so a sure-fire way to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend to consider solutions that are Free Software (a.k.a. Open Source), because only with the transparency of the code is it technically possible to validate if the code manipulates the data.

One Free Software survey tool I am aware of is [LimeSurvey](https://github.com/LimeSurvey/LimeSurvey).

An alternative to using a dedicated survey tool is to use plain email, and ask all responders to post their responses to a public available mailinglist.
That approach offers public transparency of all submissions - at the obvious cost of public exposure of all submissions as well.

If also discretion is needed, then maybe the survey can be composed as a set of independent questions, and each question then processed as a vote, using a privacy-aware voting tool.  To my knowledge, one of the best such voting tools is [Belenios](https://www.belenios.org/).